# How to draw diagram control?

Tags: c#

Is there any control to draw something like this?[image: tree diagram, I think they name it SVN tree, I'm not sure]

some cells have only one parent, some other have more than one. some have one or more child. but there is no group of child that have a group of fathers.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but it'd be helpful to know what framework/system you are working with. Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Console?

Comment: You are talking about visual appearance what about behavior of the control?

Comment: framework 3.5/widows forms/visual studio express/windows 7 home premium/monitor 20" LG/cpu core i3/3x4 m room/186cm tall, enough?

Comment: I saved data in a table in sql, one column for father code, one for his child, and a bool that says this father's child has more than one father (false) or not (true). for example: row1: 440,220,true. row2:440,230, true. this means that there is a father with code 440 that have 220 and 230 :D

Answer (score 0):

I would ask you to think about adopting WPF since this kind of job would be messy in WinForms. You can see to [FamilyShow](http://familyshow.codeplex.com/) implemented in WPF where the source is available. Honestly that's the best looking GUI I have seen on .NET. Furthermore, it compiles! :)

Comment: I have time limit to do this, I tried to start WPF, but there are a lot of differences between win form and WPF, for the littlest example, I couldn't use "FolderBrowserDialog". I'm not going to say in WPF there is no way to do that, but I don't know how to do this and I can not search for everything since time limit expires :D